# Why logical evaluation is not stopped on fist "false" result?

Tags: c#, logical-operators

`testExceptions` is Dictionary.

```
var testConfigurations = cells.SelectMany(x => x.TestConfigurations).Where(
   y => y.ID == testId && 
   !testExceptions[index].ContainsKey(y.Cell) && 
   !testExceptions[index][y.Cell].Contains(y.ID)
).ToList();
```

`!testExceptions[index][y.Cell].Contains(y.ID)` is giving me an exception when `testExceptions` doesn't contain key `y.Cell`. But since I was checking `ContainsKey` I expected it will not evaluate last condition. Is there any way to avoid exception without using long `if/else` statements?

Comment: You are checking if it does not `Contains`, remove the `!`.

Comment: You can also use the ?. to not fail if there is a null.  It would return false. for example. !testExceptions[index][y.Cell]?.Contains(y.ID) so the contains(y.Id) would not be necessary.

Comment: ah, how I could miss that. Working on weekends is evil...

Comment: `y => y.ID == testId && testExceptions[index].TryGetValue(y.Cell, out var yCell) && yCell.Contains(y.ID)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking if it *doesn't* contain the key. You need to check if it *does* contain the key:

```
testExceptions[index].ContainsKey(y.Cell) && ... use the key ...
```